# Nhibernate - No row with the given identifier exists when related records are not found

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, automapper, nhibernate-mapping

I'm have two tables in my database (Products and StockItems), in which are related. In addition, i have a view model that represents the product entity, with a list of stock items. To parse one class to another, i'm using AutoMapper.
I'm receiving an exception when i try to parse my product to my product view model, when i have no stock items related. When i have, no exceptions are generated. The message that i'm receiving is "No row with the given identifier exists when related records are not found". 
I'm read that it could be fixed by using "NotFoud.Ignore" annotation on mapping, however, i did, and it not works. I'm also read that it could be a mapping issue with the foreign key (the mapping could not exists fisically), but i reviewed the mappings and tables and it seems fine (also, the related records are loaded fine when they exists).

The code of the mapping of the list of StockItems into ProductEntity are this:

```
Set
 (
    x => x.StockItems,
    m =>
    {
        m.Key(k => k.Column("ProductId"));
        m.Lazy(CollectionLazy.NoLazy); ;
        m.Fetch(CollectionFetchMode.Select);
    },
    map => map.OneToMany(x =>
    {
        x.Class(typeof(StockItem));
    })
);
```

In the StockItems, i have the following code for mapping the Product entity:

```
ManyToOne
(
    x => x.Product,
    m =>
    {
      m.Column("ProductId");
      m.ForeignKey("FK_StockItems_ProductId");
      m.Lazy(LazyRelation.NoLazy);
      m.Cascade(Cascade.None);
});
```

Comment: maybe this helps - https://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/solved-org-hibernate-objectnotfoundexception-no-row-with-the-given-identifier-exists/

Answer (score 0):

> Ok, you get problem when sub entity not found. you can  try this 
>   **NotFound.Ignore()**  i think it will work.